# Create subsidary using Suitescript Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create a test subsidiary using script but it is throwing error 
Code: UNEXPECTED_ERROR

What is wrong with this code

```
function createSubsidar(type){

try{

var data ={
  name:'Test subsidiary',
  parent: 1,
  state: "Alaska",
  country: "US",
  currency: 1
}

var record = nlapiCreateRecord('subsidiary');

nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','16','16');

record.setFieldValue('name',data.name);
record.setFieldValue('parent',data.parent);
record.setFieldValue('state',data.state);
record.setFieldValue('country',data.country);
record.setFieldValue('currency',data.currency);

nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','16','16');

var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','id',id);


}catch(e){
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','message',e);
}


}
```

I do not want to create a subsidiary manually. On netsuite guild it is written that subsidiary records are fully scriptable so what is error in my code it is simple. I was just testing for one subsidiary using schedule script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong value in trying to set the 'state'. The internal ID for the state of Alaska is 'AK', not 'Alaska'. Only other thing to check is to make sure you aren't missing any other required fields, in my account it looks like Language, Fiscal Calendar, and Tax Fiscal Calendar are all also required fields on the Subsidiary record.